# My xpack license is valid and active but monitoring tab is still showing that the license has expired

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

My basic license got expired and I have re-issued and installed the license again using *curl -X PUT $HOST/_xpack/license* api . So when I check the license this way : *curl -X GET $HOST/_xpack/license* ;

It shows the license is valid.

{
"license" : {
"status" : "active",
"uid" : "",
"type" : "basic",
"issue_date" : "2023-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
"issue_date_in_millis" : 1686614400000,
"expiry_date" : "2024-06-13T23:59:59.999Z",
"expiry_date_in_millis" : 1718323199999,
"max_nodes" : 100,
"issued_to" : "",
"issuer" : "",
"start_date_in_millis" : 1686614400000
}
}

But, when I go to my monitoring tab in kibana it still is showing this one :

[Kibana Monitoring License expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zRCw.png)

So, now what should I do?

For your info, My Elasticsearch is running on a docker container and kibana is running into another one. Both container are running in an EC2. Elasticsearch version is 5.*